# Как отправить файл через сокет на Unix?

Tags: c

Есть клиент-сервер на Си, нужно передать с клиента файл на сервер.Получается отправить только текст

```
char message[]="hello";
sendto(sock,message,sizeof(message),0,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

а как переслать целый файл?

Comment: Пересылайте содержимое файла частями. `sendto` безразлично, текст ли слать или бинарные данные.

Comment: Мне нужно переслать частями по 5кб, но я вообще не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Прочитать содержимое файла в `char[]` и передать его в тот же `send`. В чем проблема?

Comment: Ок, а как потом его переслать по 5кб?

Comment: Читайте по 5 Кб. Можете предварять числом, указывающим количество передаваемых данных.

Comment: Подскажите как это программно реализовать

Comment: По 5кб на каком уровне? Ethernet без включения Jumbo Frames максимум сможет по 1500 передать. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit TCP тоже не сразу, есть время "разгона".

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так: "write(sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer));"

Comment: Для сокетов используется send - отправка, receive - приём. Почитайте про библиотеку socket-ов. Под вашей средой это сработало, в другой среде это решение может не работать.